# Php Class object DateTime converted to timestamp then back to date produces a 10minute difference?

Tags: php, datetime

So I am working on some file code to reorder media files based on a range of dates but when parsing a date extracted from the file name I am running into this issue

```
    $filename = "G:\Video\Home\testfolder\1-01-2012\20120101031153.m2ts";
    $filebase =basename($filename);
          if(strlen(basename($fileBase,'.'.$info['extension']))==14){
                $fYear = substr($fileBase,0,4);
                $fMonth = substr($fileBase,4,2);
                $fDay = substr($fileBase,6,2);
                $fHour = substr($fileBase,8,2);
                $fMin = substr($fileBase,10,2);
                $fSec = substr($fileBase,12,2);
                $FNDateTime = new DateTime($fYear.'-'.$fMonth.'-'.$fDay.' '.$fHour.':'.$fMin.':'.$fSec);
                $FNDateTimeRe = date('d-m-Y H:m:s', $FNDateTime->getTimestamp());
                printf(' FileNameExtractedTime: '.$FNDateTimeRe);
}
```

here is the weird part 
the $FNDateTime object - holds the date "2012-01-01 03:11:53" as it should.
however when I check the reversal just to ensure everything is good ...
$FNDateTimeRe shows the value as "01-01-2012 03:01:53"
as you can see its exactly 10 minutes less....

I checked my Timezones and I explicitly set

```
date_default_timezone_set('AUSTRALIA/Brisbane');
```

to ensure consistency but no dice !!

I am sure I am missing something glaringly obvious: any help appreciated.!

Development environment: Windows 7, apache 2.2.22 php 5.3.13...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`m` in the date format is not *minutes*, as you have used it for *month* already.  Try `i`.

Comment: oh wow...what a silly mistake...I was just reviewing the php date docs and came back here to see this ...thanks mate. just have to wait the 10 minutes to accept this one ....any chance we can just pretend I didnt ask this question ??...